# guardar o valor de uma query em uma variavel php

Tags: php, mysql, query

Quero guardar o valor de um select para uma variável php, e depois mostrar no html.

Tentei algo como:

```
function totalEspumas(){
    $banco = abrirBanco();
    $quantidade_pedidos = "SELECT SUM(quantidade) from pedidos";
    $resultado = $banco->query($quantidade_pedidos);
    $banco->close();
    $pedidos = '';

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
        $pedidos[] = $row;
    }

    return $pedidos;
}
```

O resultado da query é 23.
Html:

```
<?php
$totalespuma = totalEspumas();
?>
<?php  echo $totalespuma ?>
```

Quando tento mostrar o valor da variável, recebo:

> ```
> Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string
> ```

Comment: Você deve estar tentando dar um echo totalEspumas();, ele retorna um array, não pode ser feito assim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está armazenando mysqli_result  na array. O código correto fica assim:

```
function totalEspumas(){
    $banco = abrirBanco();
    $quantidade_pedidos = "SELECT SUM(quantidade) as total from pedidos";
    $resultado = $banco->query($quantidade_pedidos);
    $banco->close();
    $pedidos = '';

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
       $pedidos[] = $row['total'];
    }

    return $pedidos;
}
```

Comment: Deu certo, porém no html tive que utilizar: <td align="center"> <?php  echo $totalespuma[0] ?> </td>  Não sei se é a melhor prática mas deu certo

Answer (score 0):

Se você estiver tentando dar um:

```
echo totalEspumas();
```

Está errado, já que ele retorna um array, o certo seria:

```
$var = totalEspumas();

echo $var[seu_index];
```

Caso queira ver tudo que há no array, faça um

```
var_dump($var);
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente assim como exemplo:

```
$connection = conectadb();
$sql = "SELECT SUM(quantidade) from pedidos";

$result = $connection->query($sql);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
$sum = $row->value_sum;
```

E o retorno fica $sum.... vai ter que testar ai.